# What to do when upgrade to 4.6 failed, but rolling back breaks SMS?

Tags: upgrade, sms

When trying to upgrade to civi 4.6, the process does a partial upgrade and then errors out.  Recovering previous version reveals SMS is no longer working. What should I do?

Comment: This is the error -  Database check failed - the database looks to have been partially upgraded. You may want to reload the database with the backup and try the upgrade process again.

Answer (score 3):

Note that when reloading the database,  it is a lot safer and cleaner to load the database dump into a newly created database. If you reload into an existing database, newly created tables will still exist, which fools the upgrade scripts

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for adding a bit of detail about the error in your comment. FYI you can edit your question which is even more helpful. And in this case I'm hoping you can provide the exact error on the upgrade when you try to do it from a restored database and restored file system.

When rolling back you should likely carry out steps 9-13 and 16 at http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location. Can you provide more details of the errors you are experiencing after doing that?